# How do I avoid TFS & nuget upgrade errors

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I have a nuget package that holds a bunch of artifacts common to all our web projects, css, png, layout.cshtml.

All was fine until I needed to apply changes to a project by Upgrading my nuget package

This dialog appears for each item being replaced.

---

Microsoft Visual Studio

---

Error

1 error(s) encountered attempting to perform the add operation on 1 item(s)
First error encountered:

TF14092: The item $/ITEM.BEING.UPGRADED.* cannot be changed. A parent of this item has a pending delete which must be checked in first.

See output tool window for information on any other errors.

---

So basically it is saying that nuget deleted the old items then TFS put a delete flag against them, nuget tries copying in the new item with the same name as the deleted one and TFS has a hissy fit because the previous delete hasn't been checked in yet.

How do I fix this problem?

I can see how the jquery package works by only putting files in with different names eg jquery-1.0.js get deleted jquery-1.1.js gets copied in therefore no conflict. this isn't really practical for me as I want to use the same images etc and I'm not going to rename them all every time I make a change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a verified bug related to NuGet and TFS and it is currently going through the fix cycle on NuGet.

http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/4037

I have hit the same error a number of times. 
I had an MVC project with some Dlls and a bunch of other content files (css, js, images, etc.)
After trying a number of different things I found the following workaround to the problem.

Packed all the Dlls in a separate NuGet package without any content.
Packed any other files into a separate package.
Tagged both packages propriately so that users can find both packages easily and in relation to each other.

You can also create a dependency in the Dll package to the Content package (if you wish) so that installing the Dll package would automatically trigger installing the content package.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try setting "DisableSourceControlIntegration" key in the nuget.config file ?
More details could be found here @ http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

Note this is solution specific and hence has to be added to the nuget.config file under .\nuget folder in your solution. "Enable package restore" auto adds this file.

Thanks

Bhuva

Answer (score 1):

This defect was believed to be fixed in an earlier version of NuGet.  However, it has not been actually fixed until the 2.8 version, which is currently in testing phases and should be released shortly.

See issues here:

https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2606

https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1690

Comment: I just tried it with NuGet 2.8 beta and the problem still exists :-(

Comment: I have tried this with 2.8.1 and the problem continues to exist. However, the above workaround got me where I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this in the past, I suspect you are using local workspaces? Try converting your workspace to a server workspace or alternatively you could create a second workspace and use that for NuGet updates.

Doug